# XML De-serialization giving null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

i am having an XML string like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FullServiceAddressCorrectionDelivery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AuthenticationInfo xmlns="http://www.usps.com/postalone/services/UserAuthenticationSchema">
    <UserId xmlns="">FAPushService</UserId>
    <UserPassword xmlns="">Password4Now</UserPassword>
  </AuthenticationInfo>
</FullServiceAddressCorrectionDelivery>
```

In Order to map the nodes with Class, i am having the class structure like

```
 [Serializable]
public class FullServiceAddressCorrectionDelivery
{
    [XmlElement("AuthenticationInfo")]
    public AuthenticationInfo AuthenticationInfo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class AuthenticationInfo 
{
    [XmlElement("UserId")]
    public string UserId
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
    [XmlElement("UserPassword")]
    public string UserPassword
    {
        get;
        set;

    }

}
```

For De-serialization , i used xmlserializer to De-serialize the object

```
        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlString);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FullServiceAddressCorrectionDelivery));
        var result = (FullServiceAddressCorrectionDelivery)xs.Deserialize(stream);
```

but the value FullServiceAddressCorrectionDelivery object is always null..
please help me what i am doing wrong here....

Comment: AuthenticationInfo is in a namespace. The Xmlserializer should be made aware of that.

Comment: thanks for ur quick replay rene.. i shall be more gratefull to u if u plz elaborate your comment in litle more detail

Comment: i mean how could i make XMLserializer aware of the particular namespace.. ur help here would be gracefully appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add namesapce on the XmlElement attribute as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.namespace.aspx)

```
    [Serializable]
    public class FullServiceAddressCorrectionDelivery
    {
        [XmlElement("AuthenticationInfo", 
              Namespace = 
              "http://www.usps.com/postalone/services/UserAuthenticationSchema")]
        public AuthenticationInfo AuthenticationInfo
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class AuthenticationInfo
    {
        [XmlElement("UserId", Namespace="")]
        public string UserId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlElement("UserPassword", Namespace = "")]
        public string UserPassword
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```